# Why row won't show up?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, adsense

I am putting a google ad in a row, and my page content in the next row, so the two rows within the same container, like this:

```
<div class='container'>
   <div class='row'>
      <div class='span12'>
         <div class="google_adsense leader_board"><script type="text/javascript">
         //<![CDATA[
         google_ad_client = "pub-4274068129397983";
         google_ad_format = "728x90_as";
         google_ad_height = 90;
         google_ad_type = "text";
         google_ad_width = 728;
         //]]>
         </script>
         <script src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js"    type="text/javascript"></script>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class='row'>
      <div class='span12'>
         My page content here
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

But, I've noticed that google row won't show up, any idea why its not visible?
Is it a twitter bootstrap problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your code and it worked, but only after I disabled Adblock Plus. Do you have an ad blocker installed?

Comment: Yes, that's right, its because of an ad blocker .. thanks